# Search by character code in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How can I find documents which contains character 0x1F?

> {"Description":new RegExp("▼")}

returns 0 results. Also, search for new line character returns 0 results, despite fact that it exists in description of some documents:

> {"Description":new RegExp("♪")}

Answer (score 1):

On the Mongo shell, you can do:

```
db.char.find( { "Description": /\x1F/ } );
```

Comment: I am testing it now and it works great for characters starting from 0x20, but for smaller codes I am getting 0 results.